# How to route a GET request in GoLang to a particular subroutine

Tags: rest, http, go, http-headers, subroutine

I want to redirect specific GET  request to subroutine based on id.

Below is the code:

```
    func restApi(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
          if r.URL.Path != "/" {
                  http.NotFound(w, r)
                  return
          }
    
          if r.Method == "GET" {
                  out, err := exec.Command("ifconfig").Output()
                  output := string(out[:])
                  // route it
                  myRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
                 // replace http.HandleFunc with myRouter.HandleFunc
                  myRouter.HandleFunc("/article/1", returnWeekdayArticle)
    
                  myRouter.HandleFunc("/article/2", returnWeekendArticle)
                  for k, v := range r.URL.Query() {
                         fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", k, v)
                        // out, err := exec.Command("ls").Output()
                         if err != nil {
                            fmt.Printf("%s", err)
                         }
    
          fmt.Println("Command Successfully Executed")
          fmt.Println(output)
                  }
                 w.Write([]byte(output))
                  w.Write([]byte("Received a GET request !!! \n"))
         }
    
      }
    
      func returnWeekdayArticle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    
        vars := mux.Vars(r)
        key := vars["id"]
    
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Key: " + key)
    }
    
     func returnWeekendArticle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    
        vars := mux.Vars(r)
        key := vars["id"]
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Key: " + key)
}
```

But when i invoke below in browswer i get page not found:

```
http://localhost:8000/article/1
```

I want to redirect it to article when and similary using below url:

```
http://localhost:8000/article/2
```

redirect to article 2 or weekend article.

Please help.

Comment: You are using mux incorrectly (assuming this is gorilla/mux). You should set up the router with your paths and associated functions, then start a server with that router as the handler. Here, you are handling the request and then constructing a router which you never really use.,

Comment: This is nasty-looking code, for example you ignore `err` the first time then the second time the code is commented out and then it responds to `err`.

Comment: Once the request from the redirection comes in all your code like `myRouter.HandleFunc("/article/1", returnWeekdayArticle)` is gone as restApi has returned. You cannot do it like that as Burak explained, you _must_ redesign.

Answer (score 1):

```
   if r.URL.Path != "/" {
                 http.NotFound(w, r)
                  return
          }
```

> But when i invoke below in browswer i get page not found:

> http://localhost:8000/article/1

The code at the top of the upper function, above, instructs to return a not found error if r.URL.Path is not `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your suggestions, i rewrite the code as below:

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    r.HandleFunc("/books/{title}/page/{page}", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        vars := mux.Vars(r)
        title := vars["title"]
        page := vars["page"]

        fmt.Fprintf(w, "You've requested the book: %s on page %s\n", title, page)
    })

    r.HandleFunc("/books/{title}", ReadBook).Methods("GET")

    http.ListenAndServe(":80", r)
}

func ReadBook(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Welcome!")
     w.Write([]byte("Received a GET request for Index!!! \n"))
}
```